# Is there any way to fade CSS ":active" styles, or employ animations?

Tags: css, animation

`:active` is so nearly useful all the time, except for the fact that the class disappears the instant of `mouseUp` and it never looks clean for more interesting uses because of this abruptness.

Is there some way to, for example, add a shadow that fades in opacity with `animation` or `transition`

Comment: I'm no CSS transitions expert but [it appears so](https://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-without-hover/).

Comment: Set the transition on the element css, not on when you're defining :active. So if you're doing a:active, the transition has to be defined on a, for the property you're modifying in a:active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the before and after styles like you normally would for any other kind of CSS transition:

```css
.but {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
}

.but:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<button class="but">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Great solution. I wish it was a little more flexible, but this is definitely 100% workable.